# Updating an Array

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to update an object in Mongo that, among other things, has an object array in it. Other fields work fine, but I can't figure out how to tell it to simply set an array during an update.

```
var update = new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<MyPost>()
  .Set(m => m.Title, "Some Title") //works fine
  .Set(m => m.Contact, myPost.Contacts.ToArray()); //throws compiler error
```

The compiler spits out:

> Error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type
>   'FieldDefinition< MyPost, Contact[] >' because it is not a delegate
>   type.

Comment: Is the `Contact` property an array?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that. Contact is an array, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is old but it I had a similar issue and it took some searching to piece together an answer.

```
var bsonArray = new BsonArray(BsonDocumentWrapper.CreateMultiple(typeof(Contact), myPost.Contacts));
var update = new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<MyPost>()
    .Set(m => m.Title, "Some Title") 
    .Set(m => m.Contacts, bsonArray);
```

Just note that if you don't define the type `CreateMultiple(typeof(Contact),..`, the field `"_t" : "SomeNamespace.Contact"` gets added to every element of the array in the db

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't understand ur solution,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975324/update-an-embedded-field-using-mongodb-and-c-sharp/39993822#39993822